# How to keep the size of a form in Bootstrap v3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**DISCLAIMER** 
this is an assignment I got in a job interview to clone an existing website, I have no intentions of advertising only to solve my issue.

Hello, I was given the assignment to copy a landing page. I was instructed to use the libraries bootstrap-flipped and bootstrap-rtl, which are said to support bootstrap v3. This is why I'm using the older version of Bootstrap.

My issue is that the form in the middle of the page should be inline from the minimal breakpoint of 775px width and upwards to the maximal width.
however, the form starts to push elements downwards from the width of 1399px and downwards.

How do I keep the form inline until the breakpoint of media-width 775px?

here's a link for the tset website, since I can't upload the images to jsfiddle : https://testallon.000webhostapp.com/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      /* CHECKING IF TH FORM IS FULL. KEYUP IS USED AS IT CATCHES THE TEXT CHANGE ON THE SPOT*/
      $(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
      $('input').on('keyup', isFull);
      $('select').on('change', isFull);

      function isFull() {
        if ($(':input[name="fullName"]').val().length > 0 && $(':input[name="phoneNumber"]').val().length > 0 && $(':input[name="club"]').val() != null) {
          $(':submit').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      }
      $('#subscribe').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = 'thankyou.html';

      });
    });
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100% !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif !important;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-color: black;
  background-position: 30% 30%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.row {
  padding: 3% 0;
}

.description {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.training-images {
  margin: 5% auto;
}

div.container-fluid form input[disabled] {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border: none;
  cursor: initial;
}

#five-personal {
  font-size: 3.7em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#location-creative {
  font-size: 2.7em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

#call-for-action {
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#locations {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#conditions {
  font-size: 1.28em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 776px) {
  body {
    background-color: black;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%
  }
  .container-fluid {
    background: transparent;
    margin: auto 15%;
  }
  .row {
    padding: 1% 0;
  }
  input.form-control, select.form-control{
    width: 30px;
  }
   div.form-group{
    width: auto;
  }
  #dropdown{
    width:10%;
  }

  #locations {
    width: 98vw;
    right: calc(-49vw + 50%);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> חדר כושר הולמס פלייס וגו אקטיב - רשת מועדוני כושר בפריסה ארצית</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.4.0/css/bootstrap-flipped.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.4.0/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="assets/images/logo1.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h2 id="five-personal">
            <span>5 אימונים אישיים במתנה למצטרפים</span>
          </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h3 id="location-creative">
            <span>מועדוני הכושר הולמס פלייס וגו אקטיב כוללים מרחב אימון מפנק ומעל ל100 שיעורי סטודיו בשבוע</span>
          </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <h4 id="call-for-action">
            <span>לשיעור הכרות והצטרפות השאירו פרטים</span>
          </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- =============FORM BEGINS HERE -->
    <form id="subscribe" class="center-block col-sm-offset-2 form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input name="fullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="שם מלא: *" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="טלפון:*" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select  name="club" class="form-control">
            <option value="none" disabled="" selected="">בחר מועדון</option>
            <option disabled="">צפון</option>
            <option value="202">חיפה - הולמס פלייס גרנד קניון</option>
            <option value="212">חיפה - הולמס פלייס פמילי חיפה</option>
            <option value="102">חיפה - הולמס פלייס קניון חיפה</option>
            <option value="103">נתניה - הולמס פלייס נתניה</option>
            <option value="11">קיסריה - גו אקטיב קיסריה</option>
            <option value="104">קריות - הולמס פלייס קיריון</option>
            <option disabled="">מרכז</option>
            <option value="8">בת ים - גו אקטיב בת ים</option>
            <option value="210">גבעת שמואל - הולמס פלייס פמילי גבעת שמואל</option>
            <option value="207">גבעתיים - הולמס פלייס גבעתיים</option>
            <option value="203">הרצליה - הולמס פלייס הרצליה פיתוח</option>
            <option value="117">הרצליה - הולמס פלייס שבעת הכוכבים</option>
            <option value="111">מבשרת - הולמס פלייס מבשרת ציון</option>
            <option value="206">מודיעין - הולמס פלייס פמילי מודיעין</option>
            <option value="13">נס ציונה - גו אקטיב נס ציונה</option>
            <option value="105">פ"ת - הולמס פלייס פ"ת</option>
            <option value="4">קרית אונו - גו אקטיב קרית אונו</option>
            <option value="209">ראש העין - הולמס פלייס פמילי ראש העין</option>
            <option value="7">ראשל"צ - גו אקטיב ראשל"צ</option>
            <option value="108">ראשל"צ - הולמס פלייס ראשל"צ</option>
            <option value="205">רחובות - הולמס פלייס רחובות</option>
            <option value="2">רמת גן - גו אקטיב רמת גן</option>
            <option value="5">רמת גן - גו אקטיב תל השומר</option>
            <option value="216">רמת גן – הולמס פלייס מתחם הבורסה</option>
            <option value="106">רעננה - הולמס פלייס רננים</option>
            <option value="204">רעננה - הולמס פלייס רעננה</option>
            <option value="1">ת"א - גו אקטיב ויצמן</option>
            <option value="10">ת"א - גו אקטיב פרו הדר יוסף</option>
            <option value="109">ת"א - הולמס פלייס דיזינגוף</option>
            <option value="201">ת"א - הולמס פלייס עזריאלי</option>
            <option disabled="">דרום</option>
            <option value="211">ב"ש - הולמס פלייס ב"ש</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn-danger form-control " value="חזרו אליי" />
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" /><span>אני מעוניין/ת לקבל עדכונים, הטבות ומבצעים מקבוצת הולמס פלייס באמצעות מיילים, מסרונים או כל אמצעי אחר</span>
      </div>


    </form>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center center-block training-images">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="assets/images/gym.png" alt="person running on treadmil" />

            <h5><span>חדר כושר מתקדם</span></h5>

            <span class="description">מרחב אימון חדשני, מרווח ומאובזר
                עם הציוד ברמה הכי גבוהה</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center center-block training-images">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="assets/images/trainer.png" alt="trainer and a trainee" />

            <h5><span>5 אימונים אישיים במתנה</span></h5>

            <span class="description">רק למצטרפים החודש, אימוניים אישיים מתנה
          עם מאמן מוסמך שימקד ויביא אתכם לתוצאות</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center center-block training-images">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <img src="assets/images/classes.png" alt="meditating person" />

            <h5><span>מגוון ענק של שיעורי סטודיו</span></h5>

            <span class="description">מעל ל-100 שיעורי סטודיו בשבוע
                שיכניסו אתכם לשיגרת כושר בריאה ומהנה</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="locations" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <span>
                חיפה | כרמיאל | נתניה | רעננה | הרצליה | תל אביב | גבעתיים | פתח תקווה | יהוד | קרית אונו | רמת גן | ראש העין | ראשון לציון | שיבא תל-השומר | רחובות | קיסריה | גבעת שמואל | אשדוד | נס ציונה | מודיעין | מבשרת | באר שבע
              </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="slogan" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="assets/images/sloganHolmes.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="slogan" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="conditions" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <span>*בהצטרפות למנוי שנתי</span>
        <span>*משך האימון 30 דק</span>
        <span>*אין החזר כספי על אימוים שלא ממשו</span>
        <span>*ההטבה בתוקף עד 30.04.18</span>
        <span>*בכפוף לתקנון</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ======LOAD NATIVE JAVASCRIPT FILE -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
  <script>
    nl_lang = "he";
    nl_pos = "bl";
    nl_link = "0";
    nl_color = "blue";
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/nagishli2.2/nagishli.js" defer></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It appears that by removing the class-col-sm-offset-2 from the form element the issue is partially resolved, however the submitting button is nontheless pushed down and the design of the form is compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

include all the input in one form group and give the class `form-horizontal` to form and tweak a little bit to match your design requirement.

HTML

```
<form id="subscribe" class="form-horizontal center-block ">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <input name="fullName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="שם מלא: *">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="טלפון:*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select name="club" class="form-control">
            <option value="none" disabled="" selected="">בחר מועדון</option>
            <option disabled="">צפון</option>
            <option value="202">חיפה - הולמס פלייס גרנד קניון</option>
            <option value="212">חיפה - הולמס פלייס פמילי חיפה</option>
            <option value="102">חיפה - הולמס פלייס קניון חיפה</option>
            <option value="103">נתניה - הולמס פלייס נתניה</option>
            <option value="11">קיסריה - גו אקטיב קיסריה</option>
            <option value="104">קריות - הולמס פלייס קיריון</option>
            <option disabled="">מרכז</option>
            <option value="8">בת ים - גו אקטיב בת ים</option>
            <option value="210">גבעת שמואל - הולמס פלייס פמילי גבעת שמואל</option>
            <option value="207">גבעתיים - הולמס פלייס גבעתיים</option>
            <option value="203">הרצליה - הולמס פלייס הרצליה פיתוח</option>
            <option value="117">הרצליה - הולמס פלייס שבעת הכוכבים</option>
            <option value="111">מבשרת - הולמס פלייס מבשרת ציון</option>
            <option value="206">מודיעין - הולמס פלייס פמילי מודיעין</option>
            <option value="13">נס ציונה - גו אקטיב נס ציונה</option>
            <option value="105">פ"ת - הולמס פלייס פ"ת</option>
            <option value="4">קרית אונו - גו אקטיב קרית אונו</option>
            <option value="209">ראש העין - הולמס פלייס פמילי ראש העין</option>
            <option value="7">ראשל"צ - גו אקטיב ראשל"צ</option>
            <option value="108">ראשל"צ - הולמס פלייס ראשל"צ</option>
            <option value="205">רחובות - הולמס פלייס רחובות</option>
            <option value="2">רמת גן - גו אקטיב רמת גן</option>
            <option value="5">רמת גן - גו אקטיב תל השומר</option>
            <option value="216">רמת גן – הולמס פלייס מתחם הבורסה</option>
            <option value="106">רעננה - הולמס פלייס רננים</option>
            <option value="204">רעננה - הולמס פלייס רעננה</option>
            <option value="1">ת"א - גו אקטיב ויצמן</option>
            <option value="10">ת"א - גו אקטיב פרו הדר יוסף</option>
            <option value="109">ת"א - הולמס פלייס דיזינגוף</option>
            <option value="201">ת"א - הולמס פלייס עזריאלי</option>
            <option disabled="">דרום</option>
            <option value="211">ב"ש - הולמס פלייס ב"ש</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" class="btn-danger form-control " value="חזרו אליי" disabled="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="checkbox"><span>אני מעוניין/ת לקבל עדכונים, הטבות ומבצעים מקבוצת הולמס פלייס באמצעות מיילים, מסרונים או כל אמצעי אחר</span>
        </div>


      </form>
```

CSS

```
#subscribe {
  max-width: 767px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: It works, but it creates a new issue that the elements overlap each other when I decrease the viewport size, I want them  to keep distance from each other

Comment: @AlonParag You can add custom class to all columns in that `form-group` and give that custom class `margin bottom` below your desired breakpoint eg: `767px`. This will create the spacing between each column.and the overlapping is happening because of `form-inline` class replace it with `form-horizontal` and also remove the `col-offset` class `form` element. Hope it will resolves the issues

Comment: Your solutions works! thank you! but why is it that it works with form-horizontal and not with form-inline?

Comment: @AlonParag  In `form-inline` input have style `display: inline-block; width: auto;` whereas in `form -horizontal` input have style `display: block; width: 100%`. Whats makes the difference here is `width` in both cases. When its `auto` it takes the default width inherited from `user agent stylesheet ` means browser defaults. In `100%` it will adjust to its parent Element width.